# Errors creating ASP.NET Core 1 application

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have VS2015 and I am attempting to create an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application.

I select the template and also leave the defaults (host in azure and identity security set to individual).

I enter the details for the Azure instance and then when the project loads in VS2015 it errors straight away against DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0. I have tried package restore but no luck. in the project.json file I have:

```
  {
    "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Comment: could you post the exact error?

Comment: **NU002: The dependency Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6 in project MyTest does not support framework dnx version 4.5.3**   Which is strange as you can see that the framework in the project and in my references says dnx 4.5.1 There are another 3 errors like this. 2 against dnx 451 and 2 against dnxcore4,0

Comment: **NU002: The dependency Remotion.linq 2.0.1 in project MyTest does not support framework DNXCore Version 5.0**  The above error is also against this file and this error is also against the above file making the 4 errors.

Comment: Do you have any class library in your project ? If yes,  in which .NET framework version ?

Comment: Is there a reason because you use the version 6.0.6 of Newtonsoft.Json ? Last stable version is 8.0.3.

Comment: I didn't pick any libraries specifically. These are what VS added when I created the project using the template provided. I'm not at my machine now with VS2015. I'll try and install the later version of Json and hopefully that will resolve 2 of the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adrien got me onto the right track. I used the Nuget command line to install the latest release for Newtonsoft.Json. It successfully installed and I could see the change to the version in the project.json file. However I still had the same error displaying. Although it had updated the main file, the project.lock.json file didn't get it's references updated at the same time. I had to close my project and re-open before the reference change took effect to the lock file.